# what is this line meaning in C#

Tags: c#

im new at c# and to day i met a line that i dont understand, i hope can find the answer in here

````
public static void Main()
   {
      string output = String.Join(" ", GetAlphabet(true).Where( letter => 
                      letter.CompareTo("M") >= 0));
      Console.WriteLine(output);  
   }

   private static List<string> GetAlphabet(bool upper)
   {
      List<string> alphabet = new List<string>();
      int charValue = upper ? 65 : 97;
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 25; ctr++)
         alphabet.Add(((char)(charValue + ctr)).ToString());
      return alphabet; 
   }```
````

the code i didnt understand :

```
int charValue = upper ? 65 : 97;

i want to know what it mean
```

Comment: Take a look at the [ternary condition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). It's basically an inline-if

Comment: tl;dr: It means `if(upper) charValue = 65; else charValue = 97;`

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? The `? ... : ... ` or the integer values?

Answer (score 0):

Every character has an integer value. If you have a look at an [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) you see that the integer value of `A` is `65` and for `a` it's `97`.

In your code that is the starting value and then you have a for loop which iterates over all 26 letters. Then this integer value will be parsed to the corresponding ASCII char with `((char)(charValue + ctr)).ToString()`.

So `65, 66, 67, ...` will be parsed to `A, B, C, ...`